# SharePoint 2013 language change

Tags: language

I want to add or change my site collection language to dutch.

How will i do that?

Please give me the steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the Dutch language pack on your servers.
Here's how to do that (for SharePoint 2013):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108(v=office.15).aspx

After you install the language pack, you'll be able to choose the language. However, only the SharePoint builtin controls and labels will be in Dutch. You can also translate column names & the like - but that's a manual task.

When installing the language pack also make sure you install it up to the right patch level (service pack, cumulative update).

Download the language packs for

- Server: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30347
- Foundation: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35492

Select the right language before downloading.

Comment: Link that you provided for SharePoint 2010, question title contains reference to SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You find steps in this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108.aspx). first of all you should download [language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30347).

Comment: I don't under understand. I installed the language pack and configured the SharePoint 2013 Configuration Wizard. What to do know ? my English isn't that good.

Comment: @bawo, [Deutschland - Deutsch version](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc262108.aspx). After install language pack you can choose which language should be used for site template. You can see drop down on the site collection creation page. Also you will see this drop down if you would like to create sub site.

Comment: Now I'm getting a strange image. when I want to edit a page. 


I accidentally saved it and it doesn't go away.

This image is also showing on the server farm

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zdFkN.jpg